# Dependency property never being set

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

We have quite a few entities in our model that have a collection of Document entities associated. I'm trying to write a reusable WPF control to manage these documents. The idea is that if a `DooHickey` entity had a collection of Document entities named `ServiceCoverDocuments`, we could do the following in the XAML for the `DooHickey` view...

```
<controls:DocumentsList Documents="{Binding ServiceCoverDocuments, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

...where `ServiceCoverDocuments` would be an INPC property on the view model as follows...

```
private ObservableCollection<SystemDocument> _serviceCoverDocuments = new ObservableCollection<SystemDocument>();

  public ObservableCollection<SystemDocument> ServiceCoverDocuments {
    get {
      return _serviceCoverDocuments;
    }
    set {
      if (_serviceCoverDocuments != value) {
        _serviceCoverDocuments = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
```

In order to do this, I added a dependency property to the DocumentsList control as follows...

```
public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents {
  get {
    return (ObservableCollection<Document>) GetValue(DocumentsProperty);
  }
  set {
    SetValue(DocumentsProperty, value);
  }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentsProperty = DependencyProperty
  .Register("Documents",
  typeof(ObservableCollection<Document>), typeof(DocumentsList),
  new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Document>()));
```

However, the `set` part of the `Documents` property was never being called, so the control never displayed any documents.

After some searching, I saw posts suggesting I hook up to the changed event for the DP. I modified the last line of the DP to look like this...

```
new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DocumentTypeInterface>(), OnDocumentsChanged));
```

...where `OnDocumentsChanged` looks like this...

```
private static void OnDocumentsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  DocumentsList control = (DocumentsList) d;
  control.Documents = (ObservableCollection<DocumentTypeInterface>) e.NewValue;
}
```

However, this never gets called either.

I've checked all the bindings, and they are correct. VS doesn't show any binding errors, and if I put my mouse on any of the bindings and navigate to the declaration, it navigates correctly.

My understanding was that when the view model sets its `ServiceCoverDocuments` INPC property, the `DooHickey` view (which contains my control) would be notified, and the `Documents` property of the `DocumentsList` control would be bound (the `Mode` is `TwoWay` so this should happen), which should then set the DP on the control.

This isn't happening. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Following Ed Plunkett's suggestion (see first comment), I set the tracing to high, and got the following...

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=14431828) for Binding (hash=7284856)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'ServiceCoverDocuments'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): Attach to VisionRT.CRM.WPF.Views.UserControls.Controls.DocumentsList.Documents (hash=12260243)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): Found data context element: DocumentsList (hash=12260243) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): Activate with root item DocumentsListViewModel (hash=43041107)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828):   At level 0 - for DocumentsListViewModel.ServiceCoverDocuments found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ServiceCoverDocuments' property not found on 'object' ''DocumentsListViewModel' (HashCode=43041107)'. BindingExpression:Path=ServiceCoverDocuments; DataItem='DocumentsListViewModel' (HashCode=43041107); target element is 'DocumentsList' (Name=''); target property is 'Documents' (type 'ObservableCollection`1')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): TransferValue - using fallback/default value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=62777594 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=14431828): TransferValue - using final value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=62777594 Count=0)
```

If you look, there is a binding error there...

> 'ServiceCoverDocuments' property not found on 'object' ''DocumentsListViewModel'

This is presumably where I went wrong, but I'm not sure why. The `ServiceCoverDocuments` property is not on the `DocumentsListViewModel` (which is the VM for the control), it's on the VM for the view that houses the control. Visual Studio seems to understand this, as I can navigate from the `ServiceCoverDocuments` property to the INPC property in the view's VM.

Comment: *"the set part of the Documents property was never being called, **so** the control never displayed any documents"* -- that's not a correct statement. The setter on the `Documents` dependency property will not be called by the Binding in any case -- because the Binding will instead call `(controls:DocumentsList).SetValue(DocumentsList.DocumentsProperty, valueFromBindingSource)`. Can we see the viewmodel property? Also, try putting `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` on the binding, and then see what you see in the VS Output pane at runtime.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've updated the question to include the INPC property and the tracing output. Please can you see if that helps.

Comment: @EdPlunkett With regards to the first part of your comment, the SetValue() method wasn't being called, which is why I tried adding the changed event for the DP

Comment: Please note that it makes no sense to assign the property value again in the PropertyChangedCallback, i.e. `control.Documents = (...)e.NewValue`. The callback is called when the property already has the new value. There is no need to set it again.

Comment: Besides that, you should also be aware that it is bad practice to assign a default value by property metadata to a collection type dependency property (or any other mutable type). All instance of your control would share the same single collection instance.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel If you had no PropertyChanged event handler, how were you able to determine that the `SetValue` method wasn't being called?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I put a breakpoint on the line in the Documents property where SetValue is called. It was never hit.

Comment: @Clemens I only tried the callback after the property wasn't being set (see my question where I described the order the code was added). I got the idea to set it like that from some code here on SO. As it happens, it's immaterial as the callback isn't being called either

Comment: @Clemens What am I supposed to use for the default value then?

Comment: Assign a default value in the control's constructor.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Once again, with emphasis: The Binding class calls `DepencencyObject.SetValue()` (a method your class inherits). It doesn't call your code. It does not  call your setter. Not ever. Never.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, wasn't clear. What I meant was, what do I use in the `PropertyMetadata` ctor? I'm not worried about the actual default value, as the VM will set the real property

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Pass null. Null is fine.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry if I sound dumb, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing then. I'm obviously missing something here. Please could you post some code which shows how I should be doing this. I just want the control to have a Documents property, which the view that contains the control could use for binding, and then have the control's VM Documents property updated. If you could show me how to do that I'd be really grateful, as I obviously don't understand how this works. If you post it as an answer, I'll be able to accept it when I've got it working. Thx

Comment: Back to the bindings. That binding needs a RelativeSource. Can you share the XAML for the whole usercontrol where this guy lives? I *think* the binding should be this: `Documents="{Binding DataContext.ServiceCoverDocuments, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`, but if that doesn't work, I'll need to see more XAML to be sure what exactly to do.

Comment: All I was saying there is that putting a breakpoint in the property setter in your code is a waste of time; in a properly working binding, that'll never be hit. The get/set property is a convenience for your own code. The Binding will never use it; all you need for the Binding is the DependencyProperty itself. You could comment out the `public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents...` property that calls GetValue/SetValue and XAML would never even notice.

Comment: This is why Dependency Properties have the `PropertyChanged` handler: Since the setter is never called, that's the only way for your code to hook in when the value changes.

Comment: Ah, found the problem, or at least, part of it. I want to make this control reusable, so I defined the property to be of type `ObservableCollection<DocumentTypeInterface>` where each of the document types in the model implement this interface. After changing the binding as you suggested, I noticed a trace error about not being able to perform two-way binding between the interface and the concrete class type. I changed the type to use the concrete type, and it works. Trouble is, it's no longer reusable, as it's tied to that type. Can I get around this? I want to be able to use the interface?

Comment: There may be something important I don't know about the guts of your control, but I would have made it `System.Collections.IList` -- not even generic. This gets around covariance issues, which if I understand correctly is what you're running into now. In the XAML, you bind to the properties of the items in the collection by name -- no worries about type. The only question is whether the control's C# code does anything with the collection items. In that case you'd iterate through `foreach (var doc in Documents.Cast<DocumentTypeInterface>()) {...`

Comment: -- that'll work for any collection of anything where the items can be cast to `DocumentTypeInterface`.

Comment: Another thing that would work (at least with the typesystem) is making `Documents` of type `IEnumerable<DocumentTypeInterface>`. If the control doesn't need to do anything but iterate through the items, that's likely the best option. If it needs to add more items, you're in for some hassle, but you would be anyway -- and you could work around it with reflection.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the ideas. I do need to manipulate the collection, but an IList would be OK. Just tried it now, and it didn't show the documents in the view, but I need to look more tomorrow. Thx, will let you know how I get on

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Cool, hit me up when you know more.

Comment: Anyone know why this was downvoted? It seemed like a reasonable question to me, and elicited some great comments that really helped

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks again for the help, changing to a non-generic IList worked. I did some fancy reflection on the Documents property to get the concrete type of the collection's generic parameter, so was able to create the correct type when I wanted a new one. All works like a treat!

Comment: I'm occasionally dumbfounded by what gets downvoted around here. Did the binding/relativesource thing turn out to be what I thought it might be?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well, I needed the relative source, but I also needed to change the collection type to IList, so both of your suggestions were needed. At some point, I should write this up, as it wasn't easy, but is a very useful insight onto a useful technique. Thanks again.